# MVVM Light ViewModelLocator: How to register Singleton ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I'm familiar with MVVM Light toolkit's ViewModelBase, Message, but not familiar with the ViewModelLocator. In my application there is Singleton ViewModel, such as PrinterViewModel. Registering is like

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IPrinter,PrinterViewModel>();
```

When debugging, the error is something like 'Cannot register: No public constructor found'.

So 2 questions:

1. Is it bad idea to have Singleton ViewModel?
2. How to register Singleton ViewModel, since I did not find any overloads to pass an instance for certain interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) As a general rule of thumb, yes. It's the job of the injection framework to set scoping. You might have a database repository class (say) that needs per-form scoping in WPF builds (so the user can cancel the edit), per-request scoping in web builds and singleton scoping in command-line tools. Neither the class itself nor any of its consumers should be aware of what scoping that object has been given.

2) A simple (and not very good) solution would be to just add the singleton instance to your ViewModelLocator and always return that. Another one is to just call GetInstance() without a key and rely on lazy creation. I'm not a huge fan of SimpleIoC though, it's a bit *too* simple for my liking. Try taking a look at more fully-featured frameworks like Ninject, you'll find they're much more flexible and fluent in their usage e.g.:

```
Bind<IPrinter>().To<PrinterViewModel>().InSingletonScope();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a case where I wanted to register a singleton by myself, because I needed to give an argument to the object constructor.

I then registered the singleton instance by doing:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IInterface>(() => new ImplementationClass(param));
```

The object will be constructed only once, the first time that this line is called:

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IInterface>();
```